# Sylius - how to perform the checkout step programmatically?

Tags: sylius

Today I faced a problem which I couldn't solve with the manual.

I have a case that if the customer selects the cash on delivery shipping method I'd like to skip the payment step.

So far I've created an event listener on sylius.order.post_select_shipping with onCashOnDeliveryShipmentSelect method.

```
public function onCashOnDeliveryShipmentSelect(ResourceControllerEvent $event)
{
    /** @var Order $order */
    $order = $event->getSubject();

    /** @var Shipment $shipment */
    foreach ($order->getShipments() as $shipment) {
        /** @var ShippingMethod $method */
        $method = $shipment->getMethod();
        if ($method->getCashOnDelivery()) {
            $order = $this->selectPayment($order);
            $this->getStateMachine($order)->apply(OrderCheckoutTransitions::TRANSITION_COMPLETE);

            $this->container->get('sylius.manager.order')->flush();
        }
    }
}

private function selectPayment(Order $order)
{

    $this->getStateMachine($order)->apply(OrderCheckoutTransitions::TRANSITION_SELECT_PAYMENT);

    $paymentMethod = $this->container
        ->get('sylius.repository.payment_method')
        ->findOneByCode('cash_on_delivery');

    foreach ($order->getPayments() as $payment) {
        $payment->setMethod($paymentMethod);
    }

    $this->flush();
    return $order;
}

private function getStateMachine(Order $order)
{
    $stateMachineFactory = $this->container->get('sm.factory');
    $stateMachine = $stateMachineFactory->get($order, OrderCheckoutTransitions::GRAPH);

    return $stateMachine;
}

private function flush()
{
    $this->container->get('sylius.manager.order')->flush();
}
```

Once I go through the checkout process and select the method with cashOnDelivey flag set to true I'm getting the redirect loop error even though the order is processed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your business assumptions are just wrong.

**Cash On Delivery** - this is a Payment Method, not a Shipping Method.

Rethink what you are trying to do, and then come back. If you want to have a shipping method that can be paid only on delivery, then you will have to do sth similar to our skipping payment step when the order total is 0. :)

Comment: In my business logic the shipping provider has a separate shipping method for cash on delivery. Of course I can skip the checkout step based on the single shipping method code but it's highly possible that I'll face the same issue in future and I just don't want to write another "or" statement.

Comment: Okay, then your mistake in the listener is that you do not flush after selecting the payment, therefore the new state is not saved on the order ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now everything works fine except the redirection - after selecting the cod shipping the order goes to complete step and redirects to the sylius_shop_checkout_select_payment route. Is there any recommended way to redirect after setting the state machine step in event listener? It also'd be nice not to set the complete step and redirect to the "confirm order" one instead but unfortunately I haven't seen any OrderCheckoutTransitions const responsible for this state. My current listener looks like this: goo.gl/bKuXH2

Comment: The way described in http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/cookbook/custom-redirect-after-cart-add-action.html?highlight=event%20listener doesn't work as the setReponse method doesn't exist in the injected ResourceControllerEvent event.